# loop over all possible combinations

Tags: matlab, correlation, cross-correlation

I would like to include a loop in my script which finds the correlation of every possible combination of the data. This can be done manually by the following code:

```
clear all
%generate fake data
LName={'Name1','Name2','Name3'};
Data={rand(12,1),rand(12,1),rand(12,1)};
%place in a structure
d = [LName;Data];
Data = struct(d{:});
%find the correlation
[R,P] = corrcoef(Data.Name1,Data.Name2);
[R2,P2] = corrcoef(Data.Name1,Data.Name3);
[R3,P3] = corrcoef(Data.Name2,Data.Name3);
```

However, I would like to do this in a loop, I have started but have failed at the first hurdle. My attempted loop, which doesn't work is shown below:

```
SNames=fieldnames(Data);
for i=1:numel(SNames);
    [R{i},P{i}] = corrcoef(Data.(SNames{i}),Data.(SNames{i+1}));
end
```

I'm struggling on knowing how to tell matlab to loop over a different combination of values with every iteration.

Any help provided would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
pairs = combnk (1:3,2) % all combinations of 2 elements taken out of the vector [1,2,3]
for i = 1 : size (pairs,1)
   [R{i},P{i}] = corrcoef(Data.(SNames{pairs(i,1)}),Data.(SNames{pairs(i,2)}));  
end
```

Comment: works perfectly. However, for future reference, can the line pairs = combnk (1:3,2) be used differently i.e. if you want to find the correlation between 3 elements you would change this line to pairs = combnk (1:3,3)? thanks for your help

Comment: yes, but picking 3 elements out of 3 possible indices has only one possibility (1,2,3). And, what is correlation between 3 elements...?

Comment: So, from the solution provided above how would it be possible to adapt this to store an output of all possible combinations of the elements i.e. not only all combinations of 2 elements but to store all combinations of 2 elements and of 3 elements... and so on, depending on the size of the data set.

Answer (score 1):

@ItamarKatz answer is a good one. However, if you don't have the statistics toolbox, you can not use the **combnk** command.
In that case, you can download [combinations generator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24325-combinator-combinations-and-permutations) from here.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I wasn't aware it part of the statistics toolbox.